# Jquery tablesorter on column with uk date and time

Tags: jquery, regex, tablesorter

I'm using [tablesorter](http://tablesorter.com) to add sorting to some html tables however I have a column with UK dates and times, it seem to sort OK on the date portion but is ignoring the time.

Data:

```
27/01/2014 22:26:02
27/01/2014 22:26:01
27/01/2014 22:26:03
```

Html:

```
<tr>
    <th>Document</th>
    <th class="headerSortUp {sorter:'ukLongDate'}">Creation Date</th>
 </tr>
```

I know you can add a custom parser like :

```
ts.addParser({
    id: "ukLongDate",
    is: function (s) {
        return s.match(new RegExp(/^[A-Za-z]{3,10}\.? [0-9]{1,2}, ([0-9]{4}|'?[0-9]{2}) (([0-2]?[0-9]:[0-5][0-9])|([0-1]?[0-9]:[0-5][0-9]\s(AM|PM)))$/));
    }, format: function (s) {
        return $.tablesorter.formatFloat(new Date(s).getTime());
    }, type: "numeric"
});
```

What should the regexp be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this parser ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/eY8uH/733/)):

```
$.tablesorter.addParser({
    id: "ukLongDate",
    is: function (s) {
        return false;
    }, format: function (s) {
        s = s.replace(/(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])\/(0?[1-9]|1[012])\/(\d{4})/, '$2/$1/$3');
        return $.tablesorter.formatFloat(new Date(s).getTime());
    }, type: "numeric"
});

$('table').tablesorter({
    headers : {
        2 : { sorter: 'ukLongDate' }
    }
});
```

I didn't use the metadata method from the question `<th class="{sorter:'ukLongDate'}">` in case you happen to be missing the metadata plugin.

Comment: At first this answer didn't work for me when I was populating my data from a json data source. Turned out that the '/' in the dates wasn't getting matched in the replace when using toLocaleDateString() on the json data - the backlashes that come out of that are somehow weird, it also didn't like the colons from toLocaleTimeString(). Once I created the UK style date myself using getFullYear() etc the answer worked great.